# Grouping row of data with continuous dates

Tags: grouping, proc-sql

Seeking help...
I am trying to transform following table using proc sql:

[first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XSZJ.png)

become this table

[second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qAhd.png)

In the first table, each row 1-3, row 4-6 and row 7-8  are actually continuous in date but I am trying to ignore the date inbetween to come up with the second table

I am not sure and know how to arrive from picture 1 to picture 2. How would you solve this problem?
Thank you very much